# make submit button disappear when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to know if there was a way I could adapt this code so that when the submit button was clicked, it would disappear, but the input box would remain.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var Text = 'hello';

    function setInput(button) {
       var buttonVal = button.name,
       textbox = document.getElementById('input_' + buttonVal);
       textbox.value = Text ;
    }
</script>

<html>
      <input class='input' id="input_a1" name="a1" value="<?php {echo $a1;} ?>"> 
      <input type='submit' name='a1' value='x' onclick='setInput(this); return false;'>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks all for your help it's much appreciated. its working great

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply add :

```
   button.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

at the end of your `SetInput` function.

Comment: Note that using this method keeps the button in the flow (meaning it still takes up space, but you can't see it).  If you want to remove it from the flow, you could use `button.style.display = 'none';` instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
<button onclick="style.display = 'none'">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to disappear use...

```
button.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

However, that will leave the space the button was taking (but it will be blank).

If you want the space to disappear as well, use this instead of the `visibility`...

```
button.style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var Text = 'hello';

    function setInput(button) {
       var buttonVal = button.name;
       button.style.display = 'none'; // insert this line
       textbox = document.getElementById('input_' + buttonVal);
       textbox.value = Text ;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It's always better to highlight exactly what change you're suggesting - otherwise people have to scan the code line by line to try and find what has changed

Answer (score 1):

Write a js function that will hide an element.

```
function hide() {
    var div = document.getElementyById('whatYouWantToHide');
    div.style.display = 'none';
}
```

You can of course pass it as an argument, which would be the nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

HTML (no button) : 
    input id="myButton" type="hidden" value="Click ME? "

this line will make the button visible: 
    document.getElementById("myButton").type="button";

I found it much simple

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
    document.forms["myform"].submit();
}
</script>
<form id="myform" action="submit-form.php">
Search: <input type='text' name='query'>
<a href="javascript: submitform()">Submit</a>
</form>
```